# Why is this object seemingly being accessed when it shouldn't be?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gandalf3/04brhkhj/2/), the first object in the array (`???`) will end up containing values equal to the values in the `Grand Total` object.

I can't see why the values in `???` are being changed at all. Why is this? What is special about the first place in the array?

```
data = [{
    "name": "???",
        "number": 2,
        "value": 3,
        "int": 4
}, {
    "name": "Kitten",
        "number": 342,
        "value": 3432,
        "int": 334
}, {
    "name": "Kitten",
        "number": 3306,
        "value": 1387,
        "int": 1191
}, {
    "name": "Cat",
        "number": 10263,
        "value": 4239,
        "int": 3727
}, {
    "name": "Name with spaces",
        "number": 6770,
        "value": 2107,
        "int": 2799
}, {
    "name": "Jquery",
        "number": 9982,
        "value": 3535,
        "int": 3786
}]

obj = {};

function addToTotalsObject(item, objData) {
    //create an object for each object name to store the sum all values in objects with the same name
    if ( !! obj[item]) {
        //add
        obj[item].number += objData.number;
        obj[item].value += objData.value;
        obj[item].int += objData.int;
    } else {
        //create
        obj[item] = objData;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    objData = {
        "number": data[i].number,
        "value": data[i].value,
        "int": data[i].int
    };

    addToTotalsObject(data[i].name, objData);
    addToTotalsObject("Grand Total", objData); //object to hold sum of all values in all objects
}

console.log(obj);
```

Tested in Firefox 39.

Comment: You surely want to pass `data[i].name` for the `item` parameter, not `[data[i].name]`. Shouldn't affect behaviour though.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, yes, that's a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't copy the object when you come across a new key, so the objData you create for the first entry get's used both for the '???' entry AND *reused* for the 'Grand Total' entry. Both of them reference the exact same object, so each time you add the values to the 'Grand Total' you're applying those same changes to the '???' entry (since it's the same object).

The easiest solution would be to create a new object with your values whenever you need to create a new entry in the `obj` variable instead of just using the object that was passed to `addToTotalsObject`.

Comment: Or even easier, initialise `obj["Grand Total"]` with `{number: 0, val: 0, int: 0}`.